# TypeError- unsupported operand types

Tags: typeerror, python-3.5, nonetype, operands

I am messing with modules and I am trying to validate the user input along with multiply the modules. The area of the circle I haven't messed with but I will once I figure this one out. The area of the rectangle is the one I have issues with. It works the first time but say the user inputs something wrong and then re-prompts them it comes up as a none type.

**Error**

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Code is as follows:

[image: code]

```
def Area_Of_A_Rectangle():
  print("To Find the Area of a Rectangle we need two things")
  print("The Area of a Rectangle: ",Rectangle_Height() * Rectangle_Width() )


##!--------------------Validation Modules------------------!##


#-----Rectangle Height Input------------------------------------------------    
def Rectangle_Height():
  try:
    Rec_Height = float(input("What is the Height of your Rectangle: "))
  except ValueError:
    print("Please Try Again!")
    Rectangle_Height()
  else:
    return Rec_Height

#-----Rectangle Width-------------------------------------------------------
def Rectangle_Width():
  try:
    Rec_Width = float(input("What is the Width of your Rectangle: "))
  except ValueError:
    print("Please Try Again!")
    Rectangle_Width()
  else:
    return Rec_Width


Area_Of_A_Rectangle()
```

Comment: Please post the code as text, not as image.

Comment: Alrighty...There it is

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple - when you re-call the Rectangle_Width or Rectangle_Height after an error, you don't return that result.

Ie:

```
return Rectangle_Width()
```

vs

```
Rectange_Width()
```

Honestly, this should be done in a loop, not using exceptions and recursive calls.

For example:

```
while True:
    Rec_Width = None
    try:
        Rec_Width = float(input("What is the Width of your Rectangle: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please try again!")
        continue
    else:
        return Rec_Width
```